# django - how to remove form fields based on form data itself?

Tags: django, forms, validation, dynamic, field

Assume this model form:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
   sex = models.CharField(max_length=1, default='M')
   field1 = models.CharField(max_length=20)
   field2 = models.CharField(max_length=20
```

)

```
class MyForm(ModelForm):
   class Meta:
      model = MyModel
      fields = ('sex', 'field1', 'field2')
```

The case is simple - if 'sex' is Male, field1 should be required and field2 should be empty.
if 'sex' is Female, field2 should be filled and field1 should be empty in the form.
In any case, if the other field is not set, I want to set it myself in the server. Means - both field1 and field2 are required by the model. I just want only one to be editable in the form. 
I display them conditionally in the form itself using javascript, how can I enforce that in the server?

I've tried using

```
self.fields.pop('field1')
```

in form `.clean()` but it does not work as it is still required in the field level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the__init__ method:

```
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.is_bound:
            sex = self.data.get('sex', None)
            if sex == 'M':
               self.fields['field1'].required = False
```

Comment: I took your solution add just used the .disabled attribute on the field, and set the field value myself. the trick was indeed to use is_bound in the form __init__